# Minimalistic Clean Responsive Layout in CSS3 Flexbox: Desktop <> Mobile toggle

Tags: css, mobile, responsive-design, flexbox, desktop

I am trying to achieve a simple clean minimalistic responsive layout in CSS3 Flex, where:

A) in the desktop mode the body contains three vertical elements side by side "all in one row", and;
 B) an alternative vertical oriented mobile version mode where the body contains the elements as rows on top of eachother, "all in one column".

But my code is broken somewhere as I dont see the mobile version kicking in when resizing the the window to narrow vertical orientation. What am I missing?

```css
*{
      margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
         box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
         display: flex;
         min-height: 100vh;
         flex-direction: row;
         flex: 1;
         background: yellow;
}

main {
 flex: 2;
 background: tomato;
}

nav {
 flex: 1;
 background: tan;
}

aside {
 flex:1;
 background: thistle;
}


/* FOR MOBILE PHONES */
@media only screen and (orientation: vertical) and (max-width: 768px) { 

 body{
  flex-direction: column;
 }

 main {
  background: crimson; /* test to see if mobile mode is activated */
 }
}
```

```html
<body>
    <main>content</main>
    <nav>nav</nav>
    <aside>aside</aside>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

orientation: can be portrait or landscape:

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex: 1;
  background: yellow;
}

main {
  flex: 2;
  background: tomato;
}

nav {
  flex: 1;
  background: tan;
}

aside {
  flex: 1;
  background: thistle;
}


/* FOR MOBILE PHONES */

@media only screen and (orientation: portrait) {
  body {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  main {
    background: crimson;
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <main>content</main>
  <nav>nav</nav>
  <aside>aside</aside>
</body>
```

Comment: Aaaah that wwas it! Thanks +1 and acceped! it works now. PS what doest the  `min-height: 100vh;` do here actually? What does `vh` mean and what are the alternatives to `vh` here?

Comment: vh is 1/100th of the viewport height. So 100vh make the element have a height equal to the viewport. You can also use 100% for it.

Comment: Aah i see thanks. (*"You can also use 100% for it"*). However I do see when I use the `100%` instead of `100vh` in min-height , then the height does NOT get fully filled... perhaps you ment to use 100% in a different way?

Comment: When you use height: 100% on body, it will take 100% height of the parent. But the parent is **html**. So you need to go one step further and also declare **html** { height: 100%;}. Now, html is the full height of the window, and body is the full height of html

Comment: Aaah i see Thanks! +1